# Why does window's Run run program from wrong path?

Tags: windows-7, windows, path

I have python 3.3 and 2.7 installed on my computer.
Lately I decided to run python 2.7 more form Run, when previously python 3.3 was used. ("python" auto-completes in Run)

In order to do it, I changed the PATH system variable to C:\python27 from C:\python33.

When I run from CMD itself, python 2.7 opens. However, when I try to do it from Run, it doesn't work at all.

Any help? I am far more curios about the "why" rather then want a solution.

Notes:
* I tried looking at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU, thinking about some sort of cache, but the paths there are of python27.
* My user PATH variable is not relevant, I checked.
* I tried removing python 2.7's path completely, however when I try running python, 3.3 opens.

Comment: What happens if you log out and log back in?

Comment: Still the same. Python 3.3 runs.

Comment: Possibly related: [How does the start batch command execute a software by calling only its name?](http://superuser.com/q/554225)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you only have one python directory in your path varible. alternately, you can check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths to see if you have a key for your python interpreter, and if not create a key indicating your executable. some more info here: http://commandwindows.com/runline.htm

Comment: Saved me there, thanks a lot!